# Calling a custom phtml file in another phtml file, cms block, cms page, and XML layout in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, phtml, view

There may be situation when you are developing a Project, you may need to call a custome phtml file in

- another phtml file
- cms page
- cms block (static block)
- xml layout

How to do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the Example purpose we use below custom file, we want to include

```
app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Theme/templates/extra/test-view.phtml
```

**Calling in phtml file**

```
<?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Theme::extra/test-view.phtml')); ?>
```

or alternatively

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template")->setTemplate("Magento_Theme::extra/test-view.phtml")->toHtml();?>
```

**Calling in CMS page and block**

Calling in CMS page and block is exactly same

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_view" template="Magento_Theme::extra/test-view.phtml"}}
```

**Calling in XML layout**

```
<block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test_view" template="Magento_Theme::extra/test-view.phtml"/>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Very helpful. I tried to add a phtml in my custom theme and called it from Admin CMS block and it works fine. I had to change vars like {{media url=""}} to php variables because the get outputted as they are without getting parsed. PHP variables work fine to get the media path, but is there a standard way to use {{media url=...}} in phtml?