# How to display custom checkout field value in Admin Sales Order?

Tags: magento2, sales-order, custom-attributes

I have creat a custom module that adds a custom field to checkout. It is the input text field. I save this value to quote table and to the `sales_order` table. But now I want to display this value in admin panel `Sales->Order`, under Shipping Method information. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance for all the tips.

Comment: how did you saved values in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this by adding your template file to sales_order_view.xml ,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>      
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <block class="Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom" name="sales_order_view_custom" template="order/view/custom.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

and in your template file you can get the relevant information . for this you have to create 
1.one block 'Learning\RewriteSales\Block\Adminhtml\Order\View\Custom' 
2.one template 'order/view/custom.phtml'
3.and the changes to sales_order_view.xml as mentioned above ,

for more information you can refer this link [enter link description here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94066/add-content-to-order-view-magento-2)

if you face any problem , let me know , i will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works perfect. But i have one more question. How can i display this block in Payment & Shipping Method under Shipping Informations?

Comment: @SebastianT , for that you would need to edit the overwrite the template 
 vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

Comment: @SebastianT , here you will find div with the class 'admin__page-section-item-content' after that div you can call your static block or your phtml file , if you need help with that ,  this will help you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/212207/calling-a-custom-phtml-file-in-another-phtml-file-cms-block-cms-page-and-xml  , let me know how it goes

Comment: Thank you, your answers were very helpful, i did what i wanted. :)